# Behavior of $g : u \rightarrow \frac{\exp(u) - u - 1}{u^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

I want to prove a classical concentration inequality and I need to prove that $g : u \rightarrow \frac{\exp(u) - u - 1}{u^2}$ is a positive, increasing and convex function.

The positiveness can be derived from the monotonicity of the function and its limit in $-\infty$, but I still need to prove that its increasing and convex.

One can prove that $g$ is positive, increasing and convex in $\mathbb{R}^+$ because its an infinite sum of polynomials with positive coefficients. For $\mathbb{R}^-$ however, I tried to compute its first and second derivatives but I can't really get around the problem.

Does anyone have an idea of how to prove this?

Thank you!

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3662403/42969.

Comment: Hey, yes it does! Thank you both for the link!